# Defining iteration of function in set theory

Tags: set-theory

I was trying to prove the axiom of dependant choices from AC, and got confronted with the following problem:

Given $x\in X$ and $f : X\rightarrow X$, can we define the sequence $(f^i(x))_{i\in\mathbb N}$? 
Let $\mathcal R$ be a relation on $X\times X$ such that for every $x\in X$, there exists $y\in X$ such that $x\mathcal R y$. My goal is to build a chain $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that $x_n\mathcal R x_{n+1}$. For $x\in X$, I define $N(x) = \{y\in X : x\mathcal R y\}$. By AC, $\prod_{x\in X} N(x)$ is not empty, hence I have this function that maps every $x$ to some $y$ which is in relation with $x$. Iterating $f$ would prove the axiom of dependant choices, but I can't define the aforementioned sequence using axioms of $ZF$. Could you provide me a hint on how to do this?

Comment: could you develop the "by AC, prod N(x) is not empty" ?

Comment: what kind of relation is R ?

Comment: Each $N(x)$ is not empty, by the hypothesis in the axiom of dependant choices. And by the version of AC which states that "an infinite product of non-empty sets is not empty", I get that the product is not empty. I edited my question to add the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have everything you need. The result you asked for in your first sentenced is called Dedekind's Recursion Theorem:

Given a set X, an element x in X, and a function f:X \to X, there exists a unique sequence (x_i) such that x_0=x, and x_{n+1}=f(x_n) for all n.